# How to use MailChimp Exported Template to send Email from outlook?

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I have created a Newsletter template on MailChimp and exported the template. I have also used the CSS Inliner tool to convert the HTML Code.

But How do I use this code to send the email from my outlook account?

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: MailChimp is designed for you to use the API. If you want to use it you'll have to make your own webclient or somehow make an IMAP server/converter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use the import > import as text button in Outlook on the saved HTML file and it should populate into Outlook. ([ref](http://www.soltech-solutions.com/how-to-import-html-into-outlook-email.html))

1. Open Outlook
2. Select the Create New-Email icon from the menu bar
3. From the top navigation menu options choose Insert
4. Select the Attach File icon
5. Navigate to the HTML file you want to insert
6. Select the file (highlight it)
7. From the Insert Drop Down Menu select Insert as Text

See this answer for more details on Outlook 2016: [Getting my HTML into Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931900/getting-my-html-into-email?answertab=active#tab-top)

**Please keep in mind a couple things:**

1. Outlook strips out all media queries when it sends, effectively removing responsive design
2. Outlook rewrites your code into Word HTML, which can cause discrepancies in functionality and display
3. MailChimp usually keeps proprietary code inside of its templates that are not read by other email clients and can cause issues
4. You need to ensure all CAN-SPAM regulations (physical address, unsubscribe ability) are still displayed inside the email or potentially face fines up to $10,000 per email that violates it.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked, just a few padding and image issues which I will sort out though the code. But got me 80% there. Thanks again :)